# Combine Brace Expansion With Process Substitution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

Say I have 2 files (`foo` and `bar`), and I want to diff them. With file brace expansion, I can do either of the following, and get the same results:

```
diff foo bar
diff {foo,bar}
```

Now let's say I want to quickly sort these files before diffing them. With process substitution, I can just execute the following:

```
diff <(sort foo) <(sort bar)
```

What I'd like to do is shorten this somehow. I'm imagining something like this:

```
diff <(sort {foo,bar})
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work. Any ideas? I'm open to being completely wrong in my approach.

Comment: `{...}` isn't file globbing; it's brace expansion.

Comment: This is probably a job for a custom ZLE widget; type `diff foo`, then some control character to replace `foo` with `<(sort foo)`, then repeat for `bar`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the feedback. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Diff needs 2 filenames to work. `<()` returns a file descriptor of the stdout of that process; basically, your stdout is temporarily a file, and diff reads those 2 files and compares them. `<()` can only ever return 1 file descriptor, regardless of the number of commands you've shoved in there. All of their stdout goes to the same place and there's no way to distinguish between the two of them. This is by design.

if you really think that `diff <(sort foo) <(sort bar)` is too much to type, you could write

```
h() {
    diff <(sort $1) <(sort $2)
}
```

and do `h {foo,bar}`

Comment: `h foo bar` would be even less typing for an OP of this terseness :-) In fact, I think `i foo bar` might use less ink.

Answer (score 1):

The expansion of `{foo,bar}` simply evaluates into a series of consecutive tokens. What you are looking for is repeating the same procedure (`sort`) for a series of inputs.

Provided the processing gets more complex and repeated, you can hide it in a function:

```
def process() {
  echo ... $1 ...
}
diff <(process foo) <(process bar)
```

With the number of `diff` arguments growing large, you can process them in a loop, store the output in temporary files and then expand the array of file names as diff arguments.

All in all, I do not see a way to simplify your code (exempting shortening the variables or processing function names).